# Radio buttons checking based on JSON response

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox, radio-button

I am trying to load some values from json string to various inputs / fields. My solution works great for text inputs and textfields but I can't get it to work with radiobuttons and checkboxes.
Could you please help me with this?

In HTML I have some fields like following:

```
<textarea  rows="3" name="testfield"></textarea>
<input type="text" name="testinput">
<label><input class="radio" type="radio" name="testrad" value="one" checked><span>1</span></label>
<label><input class="radio" type="radio" name="testrad" value="two" ><span>2</span></label>
<label><input class="radio" type="radio" name="testrad2" value="one" checked><span>1</span></label>
<label><input class="radio" type="radio" name="testrad2" value="two" ><span>2</span></label>
<label><input class="radio" type="radio" name="testrad2" value="three" ><span>2</span></label>
```

With AJAX call I get json string like:

`{"testfield":"Value of testfield", "testinput":"Value of testinput","testrad":"two","testrad2":"three"}`

And here is the JS code:

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "test.php",
    success: function (echo) {
        var data = JSON.parse(echo);
        for (key in data) {
            var field = $("[name=" + key);                           
            if (field.attr("type") == "radio" || field.attr("type") == "checkbox") {                                
                if ( field.val() == data[key]) {                                   
                    field.prop("checked", true) 
                }
            }else {
                $("[name=" + key).val(data[key]);
            }
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: That's because you have multiple inputs with the same `name` attribute. When you use `$("[name=" + key)` and then `.val()` it compares only the first so the condition `field.val() == data[key]` is always `false`.

Comment: I originally thought part of the issue was that the bracket isn't closed on the attribute selector: `$("[name=" + key);`. But it looks like this still works. I learned something new from your question :)

Comment: @FrankModica I just discovered that it works on Firefox and Chromium based browsers but not on the Safari, so we can still consider this as incorrect

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below is the demo that you are looking for:

```js
var key = 'testrad2';
var val = 'three'; // lets say three from response
var field = $("[name=" + key);


field.each(function(){
  if($(this).val() == val) {
     $(this).attr('checked', true);
  } else {
    $(this).attr('checked', false);
   }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea  rows="3" name="testfield"></textarea>
<input type="text" name="testinput">
<label><input class="radio" type="radio" name="testrad" value="one" checked><span>1</span></label>
<label><input class="radio" type="radio" name="testrad" value="two" ><span>2</span></label>
<label><input class="radio" type="radio" name="testrad2" value="one" checked><span>1</span></label>
<label><input class="radio" type="radio" name="testrad2" value="two" ><span>2</span></label>
<label><input class="radio" type="radio" name="testrad2" value="three" ><span>2</span></label>
```

Comment: Thank you kind sir! This is what I was looking for.